# How to use multiple cursor in stored procedure for merge query?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, merge, cursor

I'm trying to insert data in a table from procedure, from below code it 
is inserting one row at a time even though more rows are available from 
the location I'm picking data. Please help me to correct this code so
all the rows which is coming from the source can be insert at a time.
Please confirm if any more clarification required.

```
create or replace procedure proc_updatepkts
is
    sitenotemp number(3);
    precardtemp number(20);
    cursor x1 is 
        select siteno 
        from sites;
    cursor x2 is 
        select precardsummaryid 
        from precardsummary;
begin
    open x1;
    open x2;
    loop 
        fetch x1 into sitenotemp;
        fetch x2 into precardtemp;
        merge into temptable a 
            using (sitenotemp as tosite
                , precardtemp  as recordid
                , pktdate from dual) b 
            on (a.pktdate = b.pktdate)
            when not matched then 
                insert (a.pktdate,a.tosite,a.recordid)
                values(b.pktdate,b.tosite,b.recordid);
        exit when x2%notfound;
        exit when x1%notfound;
    end loop;
    close x2;
    close x1;
    commit;
end;
/
```

I am trying to post same `recordid` for all the sites with the value I'm holding in first cursor. If there are 20 sites then 20 records should post for the same `precardsummaryid`. Now the extended condition is there can be more than one `precardsummaryid` so I've taken all the `precardsummaryid` in another cursor. So if 20 sites and 5 `precardsummaryid` then 100 records should pass in `sendpkts` table

Comment: Where does `pktdate` come from? It's not declared in your code.

Comment: please consider it sysdate in second query where dual is used

Comment: Also, your EXIT WHEN statements should immediately follow the relevant  FETCH call to prevent exceptions or data corruption.

Comment: Frankly I don't understand what you're trying to achieve. Please post some sample data for the two source tables with indicative records for the target table.

Comment: @APC, I m trying to post same recordid for all the sites which value i'm holding in first cursor, which means if there is 20 sites then 20 records should post for the same  precardsummaryid.
now the extended condition is there can be more than one  precardsummaryid so i've taken all the  precardsummaryid in another cursor not if20 sites and 5  precardsummaryid then 100 records should pass in sendpkts table

Comment: So yes, a cross join, as I showed in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't defined any relationship between the records in the source tables. If that is a correct interpretation of your requirements you need a CROSS JOIN.

Replace all the code in your procedure body with one set INSERT statement:

```
create or replace procedure proc_updatepkts
is
begin
    insert   into sendpkts 
        (pktdate, tosite, recordid)
    select  sysdate as pktdate
          , s.siteno as tosite
          , p.precardsummaryid  as recordid
    from sites s
        cross join precardsummary p;
    commit;
end;
```

It's not always a good idea to have commits in stored procedures, but I've left this one in.

Answer (score 0):

Is it necessary to use procedure? You'd better to use pipelined function to merge all the rows at a time.

Where the link
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28425/pipe_paral_tbl.htm

And use bulk collect to store whole cursor for merge
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2008/08-mar/o28plsql-095155.html

Comment: Are you sure? In my experience Pipelined Functions are one of those features which developers find really cool but with few use cases where they are the best solution. Maybe you'd care to benchmark your solution against mine?